# preloading show / hide div

Tags: javascript

anyone know of a simple show hide? I was helped the code below that show's div. It works fine but I need for the first link **Sci Lit 1** to preload on page load. I was told I need to do a document ready. I'm not sure how to add that

```
    <div id="sclit"></div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 1</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 1</div> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 2</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 2</div>    
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="para">Sci Lit 3</a>
    <div class="details">text for sci lit 3</div>   

    $(function(){
        $(".para").click(function(){
            $("#sclit").text($(this).next(".details").text()); 
        });
    });
<style>
.details {display:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: small suggestion: `sclit` might not be a great choice of ID names to use on an educational website.

Comment: @jnpcl: Maybe on a sex-education site.

Comment: @Wesley: +1 Internet Win Points to you, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
$(".details:first").clone().appendTo("#sclit").show();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/m4dhv/

There are other ways to do it, but this should do.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:

```
$("#sclit").text($("div.details:first").text());
```

add this in your $(function() {...}) that runs when the page loads.

seems to work, if I'm understanding the problem right:
http://jsfiddle.net/5f4zs/1/

Comment: Hey this works too! +1 [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/m4dhv/1/) with your (IMO better) version and OP's code